# Change colors of status indicator in Resharper's marker bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper, resharper-6.1

I really like Resharper's marker bar, but I have a form of partial color blindness (deuteranopia), and I'd like to make the green and yellow status indicators more distinguishable. Obviously it's not a big deal since I can inspect the bar for yellow ticks, but if changing it is possible it'd be a nice touch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resharper 7's status bar is much more colorblind friendly, since it uses icons instead of just changing the color of the square.

Answer (score 1):

With Resharper 7 / Visual Studio 2008: go to Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors. In Display items, scroll to "ReSharper Code Analysis Error Marker on Error Stripe" and update the Item foreground color. The horizontal bars on the Marker Bar will appear as this color for errors.

Same process for warnings and suggestions.

This does not seem to work for Visual Studio 2010, however.